# scroll on mouse move d'ont work on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to css and html and I do not know much about javascript. I found this js code on code pen, it works fine except on touchscreen. how do I get the contents of my div to scroll on touchscreen? Probably adding some code in the script to detect the touchsreen and disable the mousemove and replace the overflow: hidden with overflow-x: auto but I have no idea how to do this.

Thank you

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    var $gal = $("#scrolling-wrapper"),
      galW = $gal.outerWidth(true),
      galSW = $gal[0].scrollWidth,
      wDiff = (galSW / galW) - 1, // widths difference ratio
      mPadd = 60, // mousemove Padding
      damp = 20, // Mmusemove response softness
      mX = 0, // real mouse position
      mX2 = 0, // modified mouse position
      posX = 0,
      mmAA = galW - (mPadd * 2), // the mousemove available area
      mmAAr = (galW / mmAA); // get available mousemove didderence ratio
    $gal.mousemove(function(e) {
      mX = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - this.offsetLeft;
      mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
    });
    setInterval(function() {
      posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"  
      $gal.scrollLeft(posX * wDiff);
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
#scrolling-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 425px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#musees {
  background-image: url('https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_BG.jpg');
  width: 2600px;
  height: 425px;
}

.muse1 {
  left: 55px;
  top: 90px;
}

.muse2 {
  left: 340px;
  top: -15px;
}

.muse3 {
  left: 575px;
  top: 75px;
}

.muse4 {
  left: 750px;
  top: 20px;
}

.muse5 {
  left: 1175px;
  top: 75px;
}

.muse6 {
  left: 1510px;
  top: 75px;
}

.muse7 {
  left: 1640px;
  top: 15px;
}

.muse8 {
  left: 1885px;
  top: 55px;
}

.muse9 {
  left: 2155px;
  top: 55px;
}


/* A wrapper for your images to transition */

.transition-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}


/* Position each image and apply a transition */

.transition-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}


/* Automatically hide an image during hover (to reveal the other one) */

.transition-wrapper img:last-of-type:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div id="musees">
    <a class="transition-wrapper muse1" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=5&SalleID=1">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle01Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle01.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse2" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=6&SalleID=2">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle02Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle02.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse3" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=7&SalleID=3">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle03Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle03.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse4" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=8&SalleID=4">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle04Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle04.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse5" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=14&SalleID=5">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle05Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle05.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse6" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=15&SalleID=6">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle06Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle06.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse7" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=16&SalleID=7">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle07Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle07.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse8" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=22&SalleID=8">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle08Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle08.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse9" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=98&SalleID=28">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle09Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle09.png">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any of these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594445/detect-mouse-on-touch-screen-device

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not scroll at all neither on touchscreen nor on non-touch Screen!

Answer (score 0):

You need a similar event to the one you sense here:

```
$gal.mousemove(function(e) {
  mX = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - this.offsetLeft;
  mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
});
```

but things are a little different on a touch screen - largely because humans have several fingers and the touch events need to be able to tell you how many are on the screen. You are only interested in the user moving along the gallery so the first setting in the touchmove event will be the one you are interested in.

```
e.touches[0].clientX
```

I am not very familiar with jQuery and can't see that it has a touchmove method in the same way that it has a mousemove, so here is a suggestion using addEventListener. The snippet is working for me on an iPad IOS 14.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    var $gal = $("#scrolling-wrapper"),
      galW = $gal.outerWidth(true),
      galSW = $gal[0].scrollWidth,
      wDiff = (galSW / galW) - 1, // widths difference ratio
      mPadd = 60, // mousemove Padding
      damp = 20, // Mmusemove response softness
      mX = 0, // real mouse position
      mX2 = 0, // modified mouse position
      posX = 0,
      mmAA = galW - (mPadd * 2), // the mousemove available area
      mmAAr = (galW / mmAA); // get available mousemove didderence ratio
    $gal.mousemove(function(e) {
      mX = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - this.offsetLeft;
      mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
    });
    
document.getElementById('scrolling-wrapper').addEventListener('touchmove',(function(e) {
  mX = e.touches[0].clientX - $(this).parent().offset().left - this.offsetLeft;
  mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
}));
    setInterval(function() {
      posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"  
      $gal.scrollLeft(posX * wDiff);
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
#scrolling-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 425px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#musees {
  background-image: url('https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_BG.jpg');
  width: 2600px;
  height: 425px;
}

.muse1 {
  left: 55px;
  top: 90px;
}

.muse2 {
  left: 340px;
  top: -15px;
}

.muse3 {
  left: 575px;
  top: 75px;
}

.muse4 {
  left: 750px;
  top: 20px;
}

.muse5 {
  left: 1175px;
  top: 75px;
}

.muse6 {
  left: 1510px;
  top: 75px;
}

.muse7 {
  left: 1640px;
  top: 15px;
}

.muse8 {
  left: 1885px;
  top: 55px;
}

.muse9 {
  left: 2155px;
  top: 55px;
}


/* A wrapper for your images to transition */

.transition-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}


/* Position each image and apply a transition */

.transition-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}


/* Automatically hide an image during hover (to reveal the other one) */

.transition-wrapper img:last-of-type:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div id="musees">
    <a class="transition-wrapper muse1" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=5&SalleID=1">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle01Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle01.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse2" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=6&SalleID=2">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle02Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle02.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse3" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=7&SalleID=3">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle03Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle03.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse4" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=8&SalleID=4">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle04Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle04.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse5" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=14&SalleID=5">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle05Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle05.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse6" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=15&SalleID=6">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle06Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle06.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse7" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=16&SalleID=7">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle07Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle07.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse8" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=22&SalleID=8">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle08Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle08.png">
    </a>

    <a class="transition-wrapper muse9" href="SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=98&SalleID=28">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle09Glow.png">
      <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/ExpoVirtuel_Salle09.png">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works but the gesture is not usual. Is it possible to get a more intuitive movement, like a swipe instead of having to keep your finger on the screen while sliding it to scroll?
Thank you!

Comment: I’m sure it is but probably best to try various methods. The problem with swiping is that it’s not very controlled, it doesn’t correspond to ‘walking through’ a gallery. I think other galleries use a touch move, it would be worth checking. Also worth tweaking the formula that decides how much to scroll through on a move, I found it a bit too fast, I couldn’t get the feeling of browsing gently. Also be careful of Xeno’s paradox! On a finite machine you may well get to the end.